# How to determine the intersection between the camera direction and a plane?

Tags: opengl, math, 3d

I have a 3D scene with an infinite horizontal plane (parallel to the xz coordinates) at a height H along the Y vertical axis.

I would like to know how to determine the intersection between the axis of my camera and this plane.

The camera is defined by a view-matrix and a projection-matrix.

Comment: How do you define the camera and its orientation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3D Line Segment and Plane Intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168484/3d-line-segment-and-plane-intersection)

Comment: @Ripi2 I have 4x4 viewMatrix and projectionMatrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sub-problems here: 1) Extracting the position and view-direction from the camera matrix. 2) Calculating the intersection between the view-ray and the plane.

**Extracting position and view-direction**

The view matrix describes how points are transformed from world-space to view space. The view-space in OpenGL is usually defined such that the camera is in the origin and looks into the -z direction.

To get the position of the camera, we have to transform the origin [0,0,0] of the view-space back into world-space. Mathematically speaking, we have to calculate:

```
camera_pos_ws = inverse(view_matrix) * [0,0,0,1]
```

but when looking at the equation we'll see that we are only interrested in the 4th column of the inverse matrix which will contain <sup>1</sup>

```
camera_pos_ws = [-view_matrix[12], -view_matrix[13], -view_matrix[14]]
```

The orientation of the camera can be found by a similar calculation. We know that the camera looks in -z direction in view-space thus the world space direction is given by

```
camera_dir_ws = inverse(view_matrix) * [0,0,-1,0];
```

Again, when looking at the equation, we'll see that this only takes the third row of the inverse matrix into account which is given by<sup>2</sup>

```
camera_dir_ws = [-view_matrix[2], -view_matrix[6], -view_matrix[10]]
```

**Calculating the intersection**

We now know the camera position P and the view direction D, thus we have to find the x,z value along the ray `R(x,y,z) = P + l * D` where y equals H. Since there is only one unknown, l, we can calculate that from

```
y = Py + l * Dy
H = Py + l * Dy
l = (H - Py) / Dy
```

The intersection point is then given by pasting l back into the ray equation.

**Notes**

<sup>1</sup> The indices assume that the matrix is stored in a column-major linear array.

<sup>2</sup> Note, that the inverse of a matrix of the form

```
M = [  R T ]
       0 1
```

, where R is a orthogonal 3x3 matrix, is given by

```
inv(M) = [ transpose(R)  -T ]
                0         1
```

Comment: Thanks for this details answer. Are you sure that camera_pos_ws = [-view_matrix[13], -view_matrix[14], -view_matrix[15]]  ? Isn't it : camera_pos_ws = [-view_matrix[12], -view_matrix[13], -view_matrix[14]] ?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks for the feedback, I corrected the mistake. If you have any other comments or find more errors just let me know :)

Comment: "where y equals 0" Did you mean "where y equals H" ? (H = elevation of the plane along the Y axis)

Comment: Ups, completely overread the "at height H" part. Also corrected now.

Comment: Consider an alternative way of writing the matrix transform `y = Mx = R * x + T`; invert this and one obtains `x = inv(M) * y = transpose(R) * (y - T)`. So the last column of `inv(M)` is not quite `-T`, but **`-transpose(R) * T`**.

Answer (score 1):

For a general line-plane intersection there are lot of answers and tutorials.

Your case is simple due to the plane is horizontal.

I suppose the camera is at `C(cx, cy, cz)` and it looks at `T(tx, ty,tz)`.

Then the line camera-target can be defined by:

```
cx - x     cy - y     cz - z
------  =  ------  =  ------        /// These are two independant equations
tx - cx    ty - cy    tz - cz
```

For a horizontal plane, only a equation is needed: `y = H`.
Substitute this value in the line equations and you get

```
(cx-x)/(tx-cx) = (cy-H)/(ty-cy)
(cz-z)/(tz-cz) = (cy-H)/(ty-cy)
```

So

```
x = cx - (tx-cx)*(cy-H)/(ty-cy)
y = H
z = cz - (tz-cz)*(cy-H)/(ty-cy)
```

Of course if your camera looks in an also horizontal line then `ty=cy` and there is not solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There is something I don't understand in your equations. The vector XC is colinear to the vector T. So I think it should be (cx - x) / tx = (cy - y) / ty = (cz - z) / tz  Am I correct ?

Comment: No, no correct. `cx, tx, cy, ty,...`  are coordinates, not vectors components. Your equations are wrong.